# Is "regem" the subject of both "evasisse" and "adisse" in this passage by Theodoricus Monachus?

Tags: syntax, accusativus-cum-infinitivo

The sentence is from the book "De antiquitate regum Norwagiensium", and was written by Theodoricus Monachus.

> Ibi tunc quidam dicunt regem scapha evasisse et ob salutem animae suae exteras regiones adisse, quidam vero loricatum in mare corruisse.

Thoughts: I understand that the noun "regem" is the subject for the verb "evasisse". I am also certain that the verb "adisse" is referring back to "regem". I am, however, curious whether "regem" is the implicit subject for "adisse".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *regem* is the primary argument of both *evasisse* and *adisse*. It is a parallel, elliptical construction similar to *rex evasit et adiit*, but in accusativus cum infinitivo.